# What is this of datatype, parameters

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, parameters

If i read data from a db table (*Mysql*) i get this as return:

```
[{"name":"Mobile Groups","value":1,"target":null,"alias":"mb_group","required":1,"showNull":0},
{"name":"Beta Group","value":3,"target":null,"alias":"mb_group","required":1,"showNull":0},
{"name":"Delta Group","value":4,"target":null,"alias":"mb_group","required":1,"showNull":0}]
```

I can't not anywhere found what is this of datatype, but that's not a array, true? Can i convert this data to a array, i need this data for my checboxes and radio buttons because i will control it with **foreach**, it's possible?

Comment: Depends on your application Language, it is a resultset which can be iterated

Comment: I use PHP, can i do it with this application language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = '[{"name":"Mobile Groups","value":1,"target":null,"alias":"mb_group","required":1,"showNull":0},
{"name":"Beta Group","value":3,"target":null,"alias":"mb_group","required":1,"showNull":0},
{"name":"Delta Group","value":4,"target":null,"alias":"mb_group","required":1,"showNull":0}]';

$array = json_decode($string);

var_dump($array);
```

#### Output

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[1]
      public 'name' => string 'Mobile Groups' (length=13)
      public 'value' => int 1
      public 'target' => null
      public 'alias' => string 'mb_group' (length=8)
      public 'required' => int 1
      public 'showNull' => int 0
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[2]
      public 'name' => string 'Beta Group' (length=10)
      public 'value' => int 3
      public 'target' => null
      public 'alias' => string 'mb_group' (length=8)
      public 'required' => int 1
      public 'showNull' => int 0
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[3]
      public 'name' => string 'Delta Group' (length=11)
      public 'value' => int 4
      public 'target' => null
      public 'alias' => string 'mb_group' (length=8)
      public 'required' => int 1
      public 'showNull' => int 0
```

Also you can get as array converted object with `TRUE` parameter:

```
$array = json_decode($string, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) to me, more specifically a JSON array of three objects.

In PHP, you should be able to [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) it.